# The preferred approach to pass variables to blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I'm working on a small CMS in Laravel 5, and the one of the first things that I don't fully get is passing variables to a view.

I have seen things like

`return View('view', array('name' => 'your name here'));`

Or variables in a view composer

```
public function compose($view) {
    $view->with(Config::get('configfile'));
}
```

but I'm still wondering if there is a better/more elegant way to do this. For example, with the first approach, I have to give it that array at every view, which just seems like a hassle, and with the view composers, it just feels like there should be a better solution.

Is there a recommended way to push these variables on the the view?

Also, I'm talking about a set of variables that are needed in every view. for example the name and the slogan of the website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered `view()->share` see the docs [Sharing Data with All Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->share('key', 'value');
    }
}
```

it allows you to share a piece to data with all your views. I don't see any reason why you couldn't load all your config in this way if your needing to access it on the majority of views.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Route Model Binding: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding for model specific data binding. Other than that, there's no (practical) way to do it.